Determining Jordan canonical form(JCF) of an operator given by complex differentiation.
Let $W$ be the subspace of $\Bbb C$ linear combination of the following functions:$$f_1(z)=\sin z,\qquad f_2(z)=\cos z,\qquad f_3(z)=\sin2z,\qquad f_4(z)=\cos2z.$$ Let $T$ be the linear opeartor on $W$ given by complex differentition.Which of the following statements are true?

$1$.Dimension of $W$ is $3$.$2$.The span of $f_1$ and $f_2$ is a Jordan block of $T$.$3$.$T$ has two Jordan blocks.$4$. $T$ has four Jordan blocks.


Since $f_1(z)=\sin z$,$f_2(z)=\cos z$,$f_3(z)=\sin2z$ and $f_4(z)=\cos2z$ are linearly independent,hence dimension of $W$ is $4$.So option (1) is incorrect.
Also $W$ is $T$ invariant (as $f'_1(z)=\cos z$, $f'_2(z)=-\sin z$, $f'_3(z)=2\cos2z$, $f'_4(z)=-2\sin2z$)Now for other options one should find Jordan canonical form of $T$ and for Jordan canonical form one must have eigenvalues but I am unable to find eigenvalues of $T$.

@Arpit what are the Eigen vectors?

$T$ has the four eigenvalues $\pm i$ and $\pm 2i$, so it is diagonalizable. Each eigenvector is of the form $e^{\lambda z }$ where $\lambda$ is the associated eigenvalue. Statement 4 is correct.

@BenGrossmann I am very lucky that I got a reply form you.In each question your solutions are awesome .Thank you sir.

An eigenvector for $T$ satisfies $g'=\lambda g$. Then $g(z)=e^{\lambda z}$. You have
$$
e^{\lambda z}=\cos(-i\lambda z)+i \sin(-i\lambda z),
$$
So $g\in W$ when either $-i\lambda =\pm 1$ or $-i\lambda=\pm 2$. That is, the eigenvalues of $T$ are $i,-i,2i,-2i$. Then $T$ has a basis of eigenvectors, namely $e^{iz}$, $e^{-iz}$, $e^{2iz}$, $e^{-2iz}$, and it has four Jordan blocks.

Excellent solution sir.

This problem can also be solved using linear algebra and minimal calculus by expressing $T$ as a matrix. If we take the derivatives, we have $$Tf_1=f_2,Tf_2=-f_1,Tf_3=2f_4,Tf_4=-2f_3$$
so in the $f_i$ basis $T$ corresponds to the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}0&-1&0&0\\1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&-2\\0&0&2&0\end{pmatrix}.$$
Eigenvectors, eigenvalues, Jordan form, etc. can then be computed using standard linear algebra techniques.
